# Data Extraction not working in AWS Glue Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have the table data in Glue catalog:
[image]

Schema of my **source table** is:
[image]

**add_1** is struct type so i want to extract **city** and **street_address** in new **column**.

My visual looks like this:

[image]

My config for extracting data from row is for city:

[image]

My config for extracting data from row is for **street_address**:

[image]

My job ran successfully but I see the **city** and **street_adress** columns are all null.
[image]

Can you correct me where I did the wrong? I didn't find any other tutorial for this.